# use of base64 signature in a transaction

Tags: transactions

I understand that there are two types of signatures, one DER format and another a compact type signature which includes a base64 format. In building a raw transaction how is the base64 format of a signature incorporated into the transaction. I know how to incorporate a DER encoded signature but need some help with a base64 formatted signature. Can someone suggest a python or javascript library that handles base64 signatures in building a transaction?

Answer (score 1):

> In building a raw transaction how is the base64 format of a signature incorporated into the transaction.

It's not, there's no base64 representation of signatures used in Bitcoin consensus or transactions.

Message signing using P2PKH with `signmessage` in Bitcoin Core and other tools uses a feature of ECDSA which was re-discovered [after the creation of the software](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=6430.0) called pubkey recovery, this is frequently but not always encoded as base64 as a human compatible representation. It is not used anywhere else.

> one DER format

The original releases of Bitcoin effectively used ASN.1 BER, and this was reduced to a strict definition of DER in [BIP66](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0066.mediawiki). In effect we don't use ASN.1 all, but a very restricted subset of it due to consensus issues surrounding using a lengthy, poorly defined, and malleable specification.

> I really don't understand why there is a move to make a currency so complex when the original intention was for it to alleviate the economic pain and hardship on earth.

Your misunderstanding of Bitcoin is hubris, not unnecessary complexity.

Comment: My understanding of what's going on with Bitcoin is right on target. That's why many other cryptos have come up. I just started researching Bitcoin a few months ago and it only took a couple of weeks to figure out that Bitcoin has been turned into something other than what it was initially intended to be.

Comment: @PeterWuille thank you for the explanation.

Comment: It’s not, you’re just incompetent and projecting.

Comment: That's projected back to you!!!Why don't you stop hiding behind anonymity - be real. You must be the main one behind keeping bitcoin from the masses.

Comment: I’m respected without needing an identity.